# Why this error while using "includes" in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, model

I have 2 models like this:

```
Account - has 2 columns account_id and account_name

MonthForecast - has 3 columns - account_id, entity and report_key
```

I have `has_many :month_forecasts` defined in `Account` and `belongs_to :account` defined in `MonthForecast`

I am using an `includes` like this:

```
@months = Account.includes(:month_forecasts)
```

When I do an iteration like this:

```
@months.each do |forecast|
  case forecast.month_forecasts.report_key
```

, I get this error in my `case` statement above:

```
undefined method `report_key' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `month_forecasts` is a collection, it doesn't have `report_key` attribute. you should iterate through it, e.g.: `forecast.month_forecasts.each...`

Comment: If I iterate this way, would I be able to access ALL fields from BOTH the models in EVERY row?

Comment: definitely, just give it a try

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

```
@months.each do |loop1|
  loop1.each do |loop2|
    loop1.<fields in left table>
    loop2.<fields in right table>
```

This worked for me! Thanks to @peresleguine